# smartphone - pressure sensors

Tags: sensors, smartphone

I am not very clear whether the pressure sensor available in android is used to measure the atmospheric pressure or the pressure on the touch screen?
(getAltitude()/ event.getPressue() )

Do we have any such pressure sensor in iOS which could give us values of atmospheric/finger pressure?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: iPhones (and most Android phones, I believe) use conductive touch screens--not pressure sensitive touch screens.

Answer (score 1):

event.getPressure() measures finger pressure on the touchscreen: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure(int)

getAltitude will give you your geo altitude: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

I don't know about iOS.